# How to create JNDI binding listener?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

Is it possible to create listener for add/remove bindings in JNDI?

I want to create registry of EJBs that implemented certain interface.

Comment: I don't know about the listener/bindings, but you can do a lookup on all EJB's that implements a specific interface. I did that a while back.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi with that I can get all EJB's that available at startup, how do I know about new EJB's without periodic lookup?

Comment: as far as I know, you can't programmatically register new/deregister existing EJBs. The EJB container registers all EJBs at startup and it becomes a resource available for the entire duration of the application.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi application server mare registration/deregistration when deploying new war/ear/jar, I want to know about that.